# Best Way To Upload XML With XSL With PHP

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I have a PHP file that includes my `XML` file with the `XSL`, it works, however, there is a good amount of data in the XML file, so when I interact with the HTML table that I have the data in, it is a bit delayed.

I was wondering if there was a more optimal way to import the data.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <?php
        session_start();
    ?>
    <head>

        <link href="css/fanduel.css?version=1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


        <?php if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
        { 
            include 'nav_logged.php'; 
        }else{ 
            include 'nav.php';
        }
        ?>
    </head>


    <?php
    // Load XML file
    $xml = new DOMDocument;
    $xml->load('playerList.xml');

    // Load XSL file
    $xsl = new DOMDocument;
    $xsl->load('fanduel_lineup.xsl');

    // Configure the transformer
    $proc = new XSLTProcessor;

    // Attach the xsl rules
    $proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

    echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);
    ?>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/table2CSV.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/optimizer.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-sortable.js"></script>


</html>
```

Comment: *I interact with the html table that I have the data in, it is a bit delayed* ... this is outside purview of XSLT unless you reload the page and keep re-running stylesheet. Please explain what you mean by this "interaction". If XSLT transformation is running slow then post it and sample XML for [mcve]. If not, issue may be browser, CPU, or the "interaction" (Javascript?).

Comment: The XML file is a list of baseball players and I have functions where you click the checkbox and they appear in another table. It ran smooth when there were only 20 players in it, but now there's about 1,000 and I get a bit of a lag, so if I post a sample XML you will not be able to see the problem. I've commented out the javascript and it still happens, so it must be because of the size of players.

Comment: Again, this might not have anything to do with XSLT which only runs once when page loads and not with every click of your table (unless your action reloads this page which you should try to avoid).